# Command prompt denies access to folders even after changing ownership and permission

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, permissions

I am busy learning to code in javascript using node.
I have created a project file inside my C drive that I am trying to access using the command prompt for now, but it is not letting me change the directory and is giving me "Access is Denied" when trying to enter any folders of the C drive. I am running windows 10 on my laptop incase it is of any value.

I have already given Administrators (which my user account is), Users, and my specific user profile full control over the C:\ drive, and have also moved the slider inside User Account Control Settings all the way to the bottom.

But even still when I try and move into a folder with the CMD it denies me access, this happens when running command prompt normally and as Administrator..

Any advice on what could be causing it to deny me access and how I can change this?

Comment: Give a screenshot to see how did you access the file from the command.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you launch the Command Prompt as Admin, then 
[image]